VIX futures roll-over cost, why is it usually expensive with front month futures?
I have a question regarding VIX roll-over cost.
I would be really appreciated if someone can help me :)
As many people usually know, VIX futures are normally under contango.
And the roll over cost from 1 Month(1M) front futures to 2 Month(2M) front futures is usually more expensive than rolling over from, for example let's say, 5M to 6M futures contract.
Why is it so? I mean the absolute price of back month futures (such as 5M) is more expensive than front month futures. I can understand that. But I wonder why roll over cost is cheaper in "5M => 6M" than "1M => 2M".


oh right right, you understood correctly. I'll eidt the sentence!
